How to remove duplicate instructions
I have the following code snippet to generate mint instructions and add them to a transactions
    let instructions: TransactionInstruction[] = [];
    let assets: KeypairSigner[] = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        const asset = generateSigner(umi);
        console.log("le asset", asset.publicKey);

        let mintIXs = await transactionBuilder()
            .add(setComputeUnitLimit(umi, { units: 90_000 }))
            .add(
                MintV1CoreAsset(umi, {
                    candyMachine: UMIPublicKey(candyMachine),
                    asset,
                    collection: UMIPublicKey(collection),
                    mintArgs: {
                        solPayment: some({
                            destination: UMIPublicKey(treasury),
                        }),
                    },
                })
            )
            .getInstructions();

        mintIXs.forEach((ix) => instructions.push(toWeb3JsInstruction(ix)));
        assets.push(asset);
    }

    const messageV0 = new TransactionMessage({
        payerKey: new web3PublicKey(umi.identity.publicKey),
        recentBlockhash: (await umi.rpc.getLatestBlockhash()).blockhash,
        instructions: [...instructions],
    }).compileToV0Message([]);

    const tx = new VersionedTransaction(messageV0);

    assets.forEach((asset) =>
        tx.sign([Keypair.fromSecretKey(asset.secretKey)])
    );

    tx.sign([me]);
    await connection.sendTransaction(tx, {});

Unfortunately, this transaction cannot be send because of the duplicate compute budget instructions, returning with the error
SendTransactionError: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Transaction contains a duplicate instruction (2) that is not allowed
    at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction (/home/jimii/Documents/webcode/test-umi/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:5923:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Connection.sendRawTransaction (/home/jimii/Documents/webcode/test-umi/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:5880:20)
    at async Connection.sendTransaction (/home/jimii/Documents/webcode/test-umi/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:5829:14)
    at async mintFromCoreCM (/home/jimii/Documents/webcode/test-umi/src/core-cm.ts:306:2) {
  logs: []
}

My questions are:

Aren't transaction instructions deduplicated of similar instruction or am I wrong?
Is there another way of removing duplicate instructions without removing the duplicate instruction manually?


Almost all instructions can be safely duplicated. The compute budget program appears to be the only one to return the DuplicatedInstruction error if you try to set the same compute budget parameter more than once: https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/c8685ce0e1bb9b26014f1024de2cd2b8c308cbde/compute-budget/src/compute_budget_processor.rs#L84
There are currently no functions that will automatically remove the duplicated compute budget instructions for you, so you'll have to create your instructions properly or deduplicate them yourself.
